# POSTing an empty html5 date input sends today

Tags: html, validation, datepicker

I have a form containing an `<input type="date" required>`, but when this field is left empty it just posts the current date. It does not validate as empty, it does not post as empty.

This behaviour is quite bothersome, since I can not validate on emptiness server-side. It sends a valid date, so input is accepted.

[The W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#date-state-typedate) states:

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid date string, then set it to the empty string instead.

So, this is what I'm asking:

- Am I interpreting the specification correctly when I think it should POST an empty string when no input is given?
- Is there a known workaround for this "issue"?

**UPDATE**: I noticed the frontend validation was a little screwed up because the submit was triggered by jQuery. Because of certain layout choices the submit button could not be placed inside the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did read the spec correctly and it should default to an empty string; however, this behaviour is different based on the browser you’re using.

To ensure that it defaults to an empty string you can add a **value=“”** inside the tag