# How to post empty date with HTML input type 'date'

Tags: html

I am trying to validate on the server-side some user input from a form.

I have a date value which can be left blank by the user however on: Chrome, Firefox, Opera
if the date is left blank it automatically posts today's date.

I found this question:
[POSTing an empty html5 date input sends today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885421/posting-an-empty-html5-date-input-sends-today)

and unfortunately setting `value=''` on the input does not do the trick.

Does anyone know how to post an empty date using html's `<input type='date' />`?
this default behaviour is quite irksome...

Comment: I have tried: 1. setting `value` to an incorrect date format (in hopes it defaults to an empty string), 2. setting `value` to empty string 3. setting `value` to 0, still no cigar :( thank you all in advance

Comment: I probably would use `1900-01-01T00:00:00` then as a date that you can recognize in validation and set in the backend to NULL or empty. Or by posting not the entire form with submit but posting by sending a custom JSON

Comment: THanks for the reply Tacoshy, Ok, so it seems like a workaround is the best solution in this case

Comment: Are you sure you do not have `if (!isset($_POST['date'])) { $date = date("Y/m/d"); } else { $date = $_POST['date']; }`

Comment: hehe ookay thank you very much mplungjan - I had some similar code in my controller!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour

Try to find code similar to this on the receiving end

```
if (!isset($_POST['date'])) { 
  $date = date("Y/m/d"); 
} else { 
  $date = $_POST['date']; 
}
```

The code below when

1. submitting immediately
2. changing to a date and clearing it

both show `"date":""` in Chrome, Safari, Firefox

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xqa3bt2p/)

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  console.log(...new FormData(e.target))
})
```

```html
<form id="test" method="POST" action="https://httpbin.org/post">
<input type="text" name="whatever" value="text field" />
<input type="date" name="date" value="" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when I `var_dump` my `POST` I get the current date, regardless of the users interaction with the datepicker

Comment: Have a look. I changed to post to an echo site

Comment: You are indeed correct. `value=""` works. I had some code that was formatting the date in my controller, and that was making it default to todays date, ;D   thank you!